# PowerShell getElementByTagName("a") returns NULL

Tags: javascript, windows, powershell

I´d like to click on one link, wich I´ve filterd with PowerShell

Here is the code:

```
$ie.Document.getElementByTagName("a")| foreach {
if ($_.href -eq "name.pdf"){
$_.click()
    }
}
```

When i run the script I get a error like this:

> FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

But I don´t know whats wrong, here is the HTML code:

```
<td><a href="javascript:NewWindow('name.pdf')">Name of the link</a>
```

I would be grateful for any kind of help.

Thanks in advance

Here is the whole PowerShell Code:

```
$ie = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate('url')

while($ie.busy) {
sleep 5
}
$ie.Document.getElementByTagName("a")| foreach {
if ($_.href -eq "name.pdf"){ # or eq Name of the link
$_.click()
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be a problem with my IE ? I´m using IE 9

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two wrong things.

1. Not GetElementByTagName but GetElementsByTagName
2. eq does not work use like

   $url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"

> $ie = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
>
> $ie.visible=$true
>
> $ie.navigate($url)

```
while($ie.busy) {
sleep 5
}

$links = $ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
foreach ($a in $links){
    $href = $a.href
    if ($href -like '*questions*' )
    {
        print "Found Link :  $href Clicking"
        $a.click()
        break
    }
}
```